# Scrollbar in mIRC window

Tags: scroll, scrollbar, irc, mirc

Is it possible to remove or hide (hide to allow mouse wheeling) a scroll bar within a custom mIRC window.  The verticle scrollbar to be specific.

If you look to the very right of the picture you see the scrollbar.

Is there a way to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be removed.

I put together this AHK script that will hide the scrollbar in mIRC, and will keep it hidden even after resizing the window, as well as minimizing and restoring the window.

Load this up in [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and it will start working once you click on a channel or anything in the switchbar.

```
~LButton::
MouseGetPos, , , , OutputVarControl
if (OutputVarControl = "mIRC_SwitchBar1" or OutputVarControl = "ScrollBar1")
{
WinWait, ahk_class mIRC
Control, Style, Hide, ScrollBar1
ControlGetPos, x,, Width,, mIRC_Channel1
ControlMove, mIRC_Channel1, ,, (Width + 18)
ControlGetPos, x,, Width,, mIRC_Query1
ControlMove, mIRC_Query1, ,, (Width + 18)
ControlGetPos, x,, Width,, mIRC_Status1
ControlMove, mIRC_Status1, ,, (Width + 18)
ControlGetPos, x,y, Width,Height, ListBox1
ControlMove, ListBox1, (x - 18),, ,
}
else if (OutputVarControl = "MSTaskListWClass1")
{
sleep, 500
if WinActive("ahk_class mIRC"){
WinWait, ahk_class mIRC
Control, Style, Hide, ScrollBar1
WinGetPos, X, Y, W, H, ahk_class mIRC
WinMove, ahk_class mIRC, , , , (W + 18),,
WinGetPos, X, Y, W, H, ahk_class mIRC
WinMove, ahk_class mIRC, , , , (W - 18),,
ControlGetPos, x,, Width,, mIRC_Channel1
ControlMove, mIRC_Channel1, ,, (Width + 18)
ControlGetPos, x,, Width,, mIRC_Query1
ControlMove, mIRC_Query1, ,, (Width + 18)
ControlGetPos, x,, Width,, mIRC_Status1
ControlMove, mIRC_Status1, ,, (Width + 18)
ControlGetPos, x,y, Width,Height, ListBox1
ControlMove, ListBox1, (x - 18),, ,
}
}
return
```

Assumes you use mIRC with one window maximized at a time inside the mIRC client like this. But you can have as many channels/query windows open, the script can handle switching between them.

[image: mIRC with no scrollbar]

Comment: This is external program, that means if he wanted to give someone the script to use as he intended, it wouldn't be possible without doing the same procedure also. Additionally this will stop working after he will re-size the window and he will need to make this procedure once again. In total this is a bandage and it's useless in any other case.

Comment: winexp works, it is a bit of a hassel, but worth it to my eyes.  I appreciate the help. :D

Answer (score 0):

No, The scroll-bar at the main custom window, can not be removed.